# Radial boolean using Node set up

Tags: node-editor, masking

I want to create a node set up using black and white mask as a radial Boolean way to conceal and reveal object.

[image]

I have attached the file, (this method uses builder modifier).

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a  shader-node set up?

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Why do you want to do that? What's the real goal?

Comment: Hi there Robin. I'd like to know the method of Shade node set up.

Comment: Hello Martynas.  The goal is learning another method rather than using modifier, to know how to also use Shader node set up. This will help me improve my node understanding. But also for other methods, how to unveil or conceal various objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, you could just use the provided *Gradient > Radial* texture (0..1) through a threshold, to drive the alpha (or any other attribite) of a material..

[image]

... animating the threshold:

[image]